# How do I add an element to show in the beginning or end of a SwiftUI List?

Tags: swiftui

Say I have a typical list in SwiftUI which iterates over an array to display some information. How can I add a different view/element in the beginning or end of the list without it getting repeated every time the list runs through an element in the array? Example:

```
List(restaurants, id:\.self) { restaurant in
   
   Text("search bar") // only show this once

   VStack {
      Text(restaurant.name)
      Text(restaurant.picture)
   }

}
```

This code below gives me the error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'

```
@State var shouldShow:Bool = true

var body: some View {
   List(restaurants, id:\.self) { restaurant in
      if shouldShow {
         Text("search bar") // only show this once
         shouldShow.toggle()
      }
      VStack {
         Text(restaurant.name)
         Text(restaurant.picture)
      }

   }
```

Comment: What do you meant by "show once"? At which event it should disappear? Or after some timeout?

Comment: I would only like the element to show as the first element of the list, so if I scroll down, it disappears like a regular list item

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use shouldShow.toggle() in a list. It does not return a view, it returns a (void). You will have to trigger it somewhere else like in a Button.

```
Button {
    shouldShow.toggle()
} label {
    Text(“show Search”)
}
```